# How to create a height map using XYZ triplets

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB.NET and WinForms attempting to draw a 'height map' using a listing of X,Y,Z values.  The X and Y are position values, where as Z is a height that will indicate color.

```
 45,-45,8.204196298
-45,-44.75,8.13728592
-45,-44.5,8.071285973
-45,-44.25,8.006181958
-45,-44,7.941959391
-45,-43.75,7.878603815
-45,-43.5,7.816100733
-45,-43.25,7.754435659
-45,-43,7.693594097
-45,-42.75,7.63356154
-45,-42.5,7.574323502
-45,-42.25,7.515865475
-45,-42,7.458172945
-45,-41.75,7.401231383
-45,-41.5,7.345026304
-45,-41.25,7.289543171
-45,-41,7.234767467
-45,-40.75,7.180684665
-45,-40.5,7.12728024
-45,-40.25,7.074539664
-45,-40,7.02244838
-45,-39.75,6.970991892
-45,-39.5,6.920155634
```

I am facing two major problems:

First, I assume I need to use `System.Drawing` using some paint event, but how should I go about painting the XYZ values (as in, should I be painting the points on a picturebox, panel, etc?)  What is the 'proper' way to do this?  I assume I will need to draw a 1x1 rectangle for each location in my points list.

Second, I have been researching how to choose the colors for my Z range.  I read another SO post, where HSL/HSV has been suggested (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to represent incrementing color values instead of RGB changes as it is 'closer' to what a user expects in color transition).  How do I go about this?  Do I keep a static color, then for each Z difference increase the color hue?  How do I add/modify the hue accordingly provided a starting RGB color so I can use it on a brush to paint the 1x1 rectangle?